# Reversed coordinates (x, y) in IFC

Tags: coordinates, ifc

I am trying to query some information from an IFC file by reading out the rooms (IfcSpace) and their connectionsurfacegeometry. I am using a simple example, modeled in Revit and exported in IFC4:

[3D view of the Model in Revit with some added information regarding to my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJqVe.png)

I am kind of confused about the way the planes of the connectionsurfaces are defined in the IFC file:

```
#939= IFCRELSPACEBOUNDARY('3xhbPH49D9TfQKK9Lu08oz',#42,'1stLevel',$,#204,#785,#226,.PHYSICAL.,.INTERNAL.);
    #204= IFCSPACE('04KCO36993gQtA70ZBoE3c',#42,'1',$,$,#180,#199,'Raum A',.ELEMENT.,.SPACE.,$);
    #785= IFCSLAB('3e$xLVgOf3m8nQTYiFEy7v',#42,'Geschossdecke:STB 200:2441784',$,'Geschossdecke:STB 200',#755,#781,'2441784',.FLOOR.);
    #226= IFCCONNECTIONSURFACEGEOMETRY(#224,$);
        #224= IFCCURVEBOUNDEDPLANE(#223,#220,());
            #223= IFCPLANE(#222);
                #222= IFCAXIS2PLACEMENT3D(#212,#20,#14);
                    #212= IFCCARTESIANPOINT((24.,10.,8.));
                    #20= IFCDIRECTION((0.,0.,1.));
                    #14= IFCDIRECTION((-1.,0.,0.));
            #220= IFCPOLYLINE((#10,#214,#216,#218,#10));
                #10= IFCCARTESIANPOINT((0.,0.));
                #214= IFCCARTESIANPOINT((24.,0.));
                #216= IFCCARTESIANPOINT((24.,10.));
                #218= IFCCARTESIANPOINT((0.,10.));
                #10= IFCCARTESIANPOINT((0.,0.));

#942= IFCRELSPACEBOUNDARY('0WWFTh$2PB2hOrAyfp48qI',#42,'1stLevel',$,#204,#707,#241,.PHYSICAL.,.INTERNAL.);
    #204= IFCSPACE('04KCO36993gQtA70ZBoE3c',#42,'1',$,$,#180,#199,'Raum A',.ELEMENT.,.SPACE.,$);
    #707= IFCSLAB('3e$xLVgOf3m8nQTYiFEy7D',#42,'Geschossdecke:STB 200:2441740',$,'Geschossdecke:STB 200',#676,#703,'2441740',.FLOOR.);
    #241= IFCCONNECTIONSURFACEGEOMETRY(#239,$);
        #239= IFCCURVEBOUNDEDPLANE(#238,#235,());
            #238= IFCPLANE(#237);
                #237= IFCAXIS2PLACEMENT3D(#227,#22,#18);
                    #227= IFCCARTESIANPOINT((24.,10.,0.));
                    #22= IFCDIRECTION((0.,0.,-1.));
                    #18= IFCDIRECTION((0.,-1.,0.));
            #235= IFCPOLYLINE((#10,#229,#231,#233,#10));
                #10= IFCCARTESIANPOINT((0.,0.));
                #229= IFCCARTESIANPOINT((10.,0.));
                #231= IFCCARTESIANPOINT((10.,24.));
                #233= IFCCARTESIANPOINT((0.,24.));
                #10= IFCCARTESIANPOINT((0.,0.));
```

As you can see, the slab #785 has a polyline defined in #220. The coordinates match with the axes from the Revit file. However the slab #707 has a plane created by the polyline #235, with reversed coordinates for x and y. I see that there are differences between the directions of each plane, but i dont understand how they work together.

I hope that I made the problem clear somehow and I am looking forward to your feedback.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok.. sometimes 5 mins of relaxed thinking are better then 2 hours of googling.

The coordinate origin flips for the plane that faces top down. So the x and y axes are reversed. Simple geometry :| Finaly a rubber gum helped me :D

I will leave it here, just in case.

Have a nice day!